# What's the usage of "if" in a sentence structure like "n. + be + adj. if adj. "

Tags: word-usage

> Whereas Hu and Jiang were competent **if** colorless and largely
>   uninspiring apparatchiks, Xi instantly and aggressively began
>   consolidating his power, accruing enough political capital to
>   spearhead the most extensive anti-graft campaign in modern Chinese
>   history.

I saw this sentence in a New Yorker news this morning. I have encountered this kind of use of "if" for many times. What's the meaning or function of "if" in this kind of sentence form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As BillJ mentions in his comment:

> This is called the 'concessive' use of "if", where it is equivalent to **though** or **albeit**.

As such it is used to link two *contrasting* adjectives, so that the second usually reduces the positive value of the first.  In your example, the subjects are *competent* at their jobs, they did not *stand out* (they were *colorless*).

Some other examples:

> She was a **bright if lazy** student, always turning in her homework at the last minute, if at all.
>
> He was known as an **brilliant if eccentric** pianist, who executed flawless performances -- but only when he could be bothered.
>
> It is an **inspired if unappreciated** work of art, long consigned to the museum archives.